# How to solve the Differential Equation $x(1-x)y'' + 2(1-2x)y' -2y = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

this is the indicial Eq. so... 
$$y=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} C_mx^{m+r}$$ 
$$y'=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (m+r)C_mx^{m+r-1}$$
$$y''=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (m+r)(m+r-1)C_mx^{m+r-2}$$
After these y,y',y" get into eq.$x(1-x)y'' + 2(1-2x)y' -2y = 0$,
the indicial eq. would be $ -r(r-1)-4r-c=0$ so answer becomes $r_1=-1,r_2=-2$

$(x-x^2)x^{r-2}\{r(r-1)C_o+(r+1)rC_1x+...\}+(1-2x)x^{r-1}\{rC_o+(r+1)C_1x+...\}-2(C_0+C_1x+C_2x^2+...)=0$

then how do i express  $y_1=x^{-1}(c_o+c_1x+c_2x^2+...)=c_0x^{-1}(1+x+x^2...)$ and $y_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Since the indicial roots differ by an integer, you might expect to run into logarithmic terms, but here you turn out to be lucky: the recurrence simplifies to $a_{n+1} = a_n$ and 
the general solution turns out to be

$$ \frac{c_1}{1-x} + \frac{c_2}{x(1-x)} $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** One way is grouping term as following
$$(x-x^2)y''+(1-2x)y'+(1-2x)y'-2y=0$$
$$\left((x-x^2)y'\right)'+\left((1-2x)y\right)'=0$$
$$\left((x-x^2)y'+(1-2x)y\right)'=0$$
so
$$(x-x^2)y'+(1-2x)y=C$$

Comment: The equation should be $(x-x^2)y''+(1-2x)y'+{\color{red}2}(1-2x)y'-2y=0$.